# Struct Layout with array disables tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper, visual-studio-2022, mstest

Creating a packed struct in C# that contains an array causes all tests in my test project to produce an inconclusive result. In the case of Resharper's test runner, it produces the exit code 14942211. Mstest won't run the tests either. Given StructA below as an example, if I replace the array with individual bytes, everything works. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct StructA
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] Values;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint Code;

    public StructA(byte[] values)
    {
        Code = 0;
        Values = values;
    }
    public StructA(uint code)
    {
        Values = new byte[4];
        Code = code;
    }

    public StructA()
    {
        Values = new byte[4];
        Code = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not allowed to overlap object and non-object fields in a struct. [See e.g. here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgBgARwIwDoBK1gEsC2ApugJJTCFgD2ADgMqUBuuAxoQM4DcAsAFB9RCAdyR1gkFsACCACgCUPfrwDaYicAAyAQwCeVCMBna9BgNK4oAE3QBRAB40ANq1zA5AXT4WKYKFsdI7OIQkqLBklJ8AN58SHFIygBiuISOlgDyAGaZ7ISGCB6x8XAAzEgARjoUyu5IAGr+EByKRXFJKWlZOXkyBZ688ShlEN5IAMJUloQtA8VlaiHSMpXVtYyNHHKtSDGzg3ETU0gAvEgIivvxDY5N7CdI6zfN2wC+26Vh6rIj5Egsk4QtnsdttBtdbvdBCIVoRlAAWdwXS7jAH3f5TJFxN5KQYfBYReTbXbI+obO6nKEVKqwhGY/aHQj3c6vPgvIA)

Comment: You'd need to marshal the array manually, and change the field to `public IntPtr Values;`

Comment: You have an overlay where two object are a same location (offset 0).  The object Values need to be always 4 bytes.  So you need to add [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)].  The will always put the StructA at same offset.

Comment: None of this works, it all compiles but the test runners pass-out on any test.

Comment: What are you even trying to do? You do realise that arrays are reference types, correct? So you're not overlaying a uint and 4 bytes, you're trying to overlay a uint and a pointer to an array containing 4 bytes

Comment: @canton7 I'd like to know why it compiles and yet an entire test project stops working

Comment: The compiler doesn't notice the problem. It's only when you come to load the assembly that the runtime notices the problem and reports an error

Comment: After all, those attributes are interpreted by the runtime -- the compiler doesn't care about them